# Local Bit components repository

Tags: bit.dev

Is it possible to use Bit for a team without using paid 'Team' services on bit.cloud?

Basically we just want to use as a private components library and dependency manager, without using all those paid features and public components library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with some limitations. For example, you can only add up to 10 collaborators. It could be done.

Source: https://bit.cloud/pricing

Answer (score 0):

If the limitations on the free plan are too much, you can [host your own bit scope](https://bit.dev/reference/scope/running-a-scope-server) inside your organization. Any resulting npm packages can also be [published to your own package registry](https://bit.dev/reference/packages/publishing-components-to-commonjs-registries#publish-your-components-to-any-commonjs-package-registry)